# Why use State Preservation and Restoration?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

Since a week I have been going through all the docs regarding **State Preservation and Restoration**. I also got the idea behind that. I created a demo app following the steps given here :

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_6_iPhone_State_Preservation_and_Restoration_Tutorial

And this demo app works well in the Simulator. My question is, when I m trying this in my app. The state is preserved even if I am not implementing **State Preservation and Restoration**.

If I put my app in background by clicking home button and if I again start it from the background, the same view gets opened and the app is in the same state as I left it. Then what is the need for implementing **State Preservation and Restoration**?

Can any one guide me on this?
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, simply backgrounding an app keeps it's state. But then, when iOS terminates your app, you'll lose everything not saved. Or maybe your app crashes, or phone shuts down.

This is where you can use restoration and save your inputs/hierarchy/etc.

Comment: I am still in confusion, so this feature is just used for avoiding such circumstances? If phone shuts, then aren't all the apps killed? Then what is the meaning.

Comment: Yes, but you have a chance here to keep data in your restoration values. Like I said, the simplest scenario is when you app is terminated after background time is out.

Comment: Yes you have a point. Let me try this one out and then get back to you.

Comment: iOS terminates your apps based on the need. For example you are launching a memory intensive game then there is no guarantee that iOS will keep existing apps in memory. It is in such cases saving state helps/

Comment: I don't think it restores your UI state if your app crashes - just did some testing and it doesn't seem to restore.

Comment: Hey Bob, I don't even remember why I mentioned crashing, but yeah it makes sense not to restore, because if the crash was caused by the state of your UI then you're in a crash loop :)

Answer (score 1):

Its keep state as it is..

You can check Apple's apps, for example: Notes App

First create new note.
       [image: creat]

Now close app
       [image: Close]

Now open Notes app. It keeps state when you closed it.
      [image: open]